# Postgres: "Commit transaction" stuck running for 25 minutes already

Tags: postgresql, commit

The application I support runs on postgres. Some queries were running on the db for days, so I cleaned them up to monitor the evolution.

Since I restarted a "commit transaction" has been running (25 minutes already).

I have looked on the internet and do not find a way to identify which query has triggered this commit.

Also, I wonder why a commit would take so much time. The query has already ran, if the commit has been triggered, no?

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards,

Julien

Comment: Where exactly do you see that `COMMIT`? In `pg_stat_activity`? Is the `state` active? If yes, your disk has a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this specific query is idling for 50 minutes.

Another one that has been running for 30 minutes now is active.

Comment: I have done that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State `idle` means that the `COMMIT` is no longer running, it just happened to be the last command run on this connection.

If a `COMMIT` stays `active` for any length of time, you have an I/O problem (or you are using synchronous replication).